# Changed plesk root name, what DNS settings get modified?

Tags: domains, dns, nameserver, plesk

We recently changed our Plesk server's main URL from siteold.com to sitenew.com.

Many websites had their NS set to ns1.siteold.com - does Plesk automatically update that to need ns1.sitenew.com? Should I change the GoDaddy settings? Attempting to change them states "Nameserver Not Registered" - is this simply the delay required?

Lastly, when adding a new domain to Plesk, one would simply need to adjust the nameserver for that site in GoDaddy to ns1.sitenew.com or ns1.newdomain.com (does Plesk have a centralized name server, or does each site acquire its own?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some more research ->

plesk automatically creates A records for ns.domain.com, however does not assume ns1. and ns2. -> you can modify the default settings to do this if you would like

you then have to enter godaddy's domain management and set the nameservers there to the IP of your main server

as the IP is targetted rather than the name, when changing the root domain, it doesn't actually matter -> plesk maintains its own nameserver to update

Answer (score 0):

Did you create an A Record for the sitenew.com?

Additionally, you may need to register the nameservers with GoDaddy. I use Namecheap so I can't tell you exactly how to do that, but it's likely a control panel option on the domain.